TypeORM CLI doesn't properly work with import aliases
I’ve encountered an issue where the TypeORM CLI doesn’t seem to recognize these aliases, leading to module resolution errors during migration generation.Is there a way how to fix it?
import {
  Column,
  CreateDateColumn,
  Entity,
  JoinColumn,
  ManyToOne,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm';
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';

import { Gender, ProductStatus } from '~/common/enums';
import { ImageEntity } from './image.entity';
import { SizeEntity } from './size.entity';
import { CategoryEntity } from './category.entity';
import { ColorEntity } from './colors.entity';
import { StyleEntity } from './style.entity';
import { BrandEntity } from './brand.entity';
import { MaterialEntity } from './material.entity';

@Entity({ name: 'products' })
export class ProductEntity {
  @ApiProperty({
    type: Number,
    description: 'This is an id that identifies a test entity',
  })
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @ApiProperty({
    type: String,
    description: 'This is the name of the product',
  })
  @Column({ type: 'text' })
  name: string;

  @ApiProperty({
    type: String,
    description: 'This is the description of the product',
  })
  @Column({ type: 'text' })
  description: string;

  @ApiProperty({
    type: Number,
    description: 'This is the quantity of the product',
  })
  @Column({ type: 'int' })
  quantity: number;

  @ApiProperty({
    type: String,
    enum: Gender,
    description: 'This is the gender of the product',
  })
  @Column({ type: 'enum', enum: Gender })
  gender: Gender;

  @ApiProperty({
    type: String,
    enum: ProductStatus,
    description:
      'This is the status of the product (for sale, for rent, or both)',
  })
  @Column({ type: 'enum', enum: ProductStatus })
  status: ProductStatus;

  @ApiProperty({
    type: Number,
    description: 'This is the minimum price of the product',
  })
  @Column({ type: 'decimal', precision: 10, scale: 2, name: 'min_price' })
  minPrice: number;

  @ApiProperty({
    type: Number,
    description: 'This is the maximum price of the product',
  })
  @Column({ type: 'decimal', precision: 10, scale: 2, name: 'max_price' })
  maxPrice: number;

  @ApiProperty({
    type: Number,
    description: 'Reference to the image entity',
  })
  @ManyToOne(() => ImageEntity)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'image_id' })
  image: ImageEntity;

  @ApiProperty({
    type: Number,
    description: 'Reference to the size entity',
  })
  @ManyToOne(() => SizeEntity)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'size_id' })
  size: SizeEntity;

  @ApiProperty({
    type: Number,
    description: 'Reference to the category entity',
  })
  @ManyToOne(() => CategoryEntity)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'category_id' })
  category: CategoryEntity;

  @ApiProperty({
    type: Number,
    description: 'Reference to the color entity',
  })
  @ManyToOne(() => ColorEntity)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'color_id' })
  color: ColorEntity;

  @ApiProperty({
    type: Number,
    description: 'Reference to the style entity',
  })
  @ManyToOne(() => StyleEntity)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'style_id' })
  style: StyleEntity;

  @ApiProperty({
    type: Number,
    description: 'Reference to the brand entity',
  })
  @ManyToOne(() => BrandEntity)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'brand_id' })
  brand: BrandEntity;

  @ApiProperty({
    type: Number,
    description: 'Reference to the material entity',
  })
  @ManyToOne(() => MaterialEntity)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'material_id' })
  material: MaterialEntity;

  @ApiProperty({
    type: Number,
    description: 'This is the time when product was created',
  })
  @CreateDateColumn({ name: 'created_at' })
  createdAt: Date;

  @ApiProperty({
    type: Number,
    description: 'This is the time when product was updated',
  })
  @CreateDateColumn({ name: 'updated_at' })
  updatedAt: Date;
}

When running typeorm-ts-node-commonjs migration:run
Error: Cannot find module '~/common/enums'
So seems like there is an error when working with TypeORM CLI and resolving pathes with alieases

I don't think ~/common/enums is a right path, you should check your enum path and matches right path, I was do like this:
import { ROLE_TYPES } from '../utils/common/enum';

and my tree like this:
src
  ├── common
  │        ├── dto.ts
  │        ├── enum.ts
  │        ├── errors.ts
  │        ├── handle.ts


or you can put your enum inside the entity and export it

i added alias "~" for src dir
